# Unable to call server side functions on update and delete functionality of Kendo UI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, grid

I am using MVC with WEB API in my application. I am using Kendo Grid with pop up editing. I am able to fetch the data and bind the grid. But the problem arises when i try to edit or delete a row. the operation parameter of **parameterMap: function(options, operation)** keep showing up as **create** and the same create transport url is hit in case of update and destroy.

What am i doing wrong in this code:

```
dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        type: "json",
        transport: {
            read: {
                cache: false,
                url: GETUSER_API_URL,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
                datatype: "json"
            },
            create: {
                cache: false,
                url: UPDATEUSER_API_URL,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "json"
            },
            update: {
                cache: false,
                url: UPDATEUSER_API_URL,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "json"
            },
            destroy: {
                url: DELETEUSER_API_URL,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: "POST", 
                datatype: "json"
            },
            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                debugger;
                if (operation == "update" || operation == "create") {
                    if (options.models[0].UserProfileId == null && operation != "destroy") {
                        operation = "create";
                    }
                    else {
                        operation = "update";
                    }
                    return kendo.stringify({ models: options.models[0] });
                }
                else if (operation == "destroy") {

                    return kendo.stringify({ models: options.models[0] });
                }
            }
        },
        batch: true,
        pageSize: 10,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "UserProfileID",
                fields: {
                    FirstName: { validation: { required: true } },
                    LastName: { validation: { required: true } },
                    EmailId: { nullable: false, validation: { required: true } }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

**Moreover how do i send the rows data back to the API?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try configure your webconfig with that configuration:

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

I had the same issue, but when I add `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />`
 the webapi work fine.